# Robocopied Junction not Showing Icon? Robocopied Symbolic Link also Not Showing Icon?

Tags: windows-7, windows, icons, symbolic-link, robocopy

I'm not familiar with how robocopy handles junctions, symbolic links, and hard links.  I tried to copy one of each, and I noticed the icon that shows over a junction and symbolic link does not seem to show in the copies.

I used a file comparison tool and it says one file has a reparse point, while the other does not.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use FastCopy instead.  It handles the junctions and symbolic links.http://download.cnet.com/FastCopy/3000-2248_4-10905019.html